# Which ID do I need to use as Subscriber Key in Marketing Cloud to keep in sync with Service/Sales Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, contact, salesforce-id, service-cloud-console, subscriber-key

I'm currently about to start an IP warm-up for Marketing Cloud and I have done the following:

- Imported my warm-up dataset to Service Cloud (to obtain Contact ID)
- Exported the dataset from Service Cloud with Contact ID

I've now seen this: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_subscriber_key.htm&type=5

It appears the recommendation is to not use the 15-digit Contact ID but to use an 18-digit CASESAFEID as the Subscriber Key in Marketing Cloud.

Does this mean I need to re-run my Service Cloud report with the formula to get the extra ID and also, does this mean that when we add contacts to Service Cloud via API calls and retrieve the Contact ID to store in our own database, we'll also need the 18-digit one and not the 15-digit one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General rule is that it should always be the 18-digit ID from Salesforce.

In case you are using Synchronised Data Extensions, Salesforce Report Imports / Sends or Salesforce Campaign Imports / Sends through the UI features, then the default 15-digit ID **will be automatically converted** to 18-digit ID before it lands in Marketing Cloud.

However if you are exporting a list of ID's in their 15-digit state, then there are actually some validation rules in place in MC that prevent you from uploading these to Marketing Cloud as SubscriberKey's.

The error will be with status code **[CaseSensitiveSalesforceID](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000312821&type=1&mode=1)**.

So if you're ever doing manual exports/imports then you will need to convert the ID's to 18-digit before uploading them to Marketing Cloud. For any built-in Marketing Cloud Connect scenarios, the ID's will be automatically converted.

Comment: We're in a halfway house scenario to start with unfortunately as our Service Cloud instance won't have much in the way of a custom data structure, so in the beginning we hoped to create our IP calls to add new contacts to Salesforce, have Marketing Cloud Connect sync contacts to Marketing Cloud, and have a .csv file sent to Marketing Cloud (in a non-sendable DE) to relate to to grab the extra info needed for segmentation. This file would have Contact ID. Will we be able to retrieve the 18-digit one via our API calls to store in our DB and make this process work?